# Alternative ways for iterator chaining in List Comprehension?

Tags: python, list, iterator, list-comprehension

I want to chain two or more different iterators together in list comprehension.

Assume I want to combine uppercase and lowercase letters into a list. The original way I though was like this,

```
lst1 = [chr(i) for i in range(97,123)]
lst2 = [chr(i) for i in range(65,91)]
lst = lst1+lst2
```

However I thought there must be some other ways to do this nicely in a single line, and then I used this with itertools module,

```
lst = [chr(i) for i in itertools.chain(range(97,123), range(65,91))]
```

In the end I also thought of tuple unpacking,

```
lst = [chr(i) for i in (*range(97,123), *range(65,91))]
```

*Itertools was slower compared with two other methods (tuple unpacking was the fastest one)*

For example, characters in the first range and the second range make the list of

```
>>> lst1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

>>> lst2
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

I want them merged with only 1 iterator, not two separate ones. The example of the merged list, where 2 different ranges of values are used is given below,

```
>>> lst
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Is there any way to improve this or change the design?

Comment: Have you tried `itertools.chain` both of the generators instead of the ranges? `list(itertools.chain((chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)), (chr(i) for i in range(65, 91))))`

Comment: Could you please provide an example output, so we can see exactly what solution you are looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've found the correct solution(s).

Note: `itertools.chain` may be trivially slower, but it has the advantage of being (effectively) zero memory overhead, and I'd recommend it in general. `range` is already (effectively) zero memory overhead, so using it with `chain` means no meaningful memory overhead at all, while using unpacking to a `tuple` involves realizing both `range`s as a `tuple` for no real reason. If the sizes never increase, then whatever, but if the inputs might be variable length, `chain` is safer than realizing an unbounded iterable in memory.

Of course, for your specific case, the obvious solution (that's significantly more readable) is:

```
 import string

 lst = list(string.ascii_letters)
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative way that provides the same order of letters (capital letters last despite being a lower numeric value). I totally expected `list(string.ascii_letters)` to be ordered in the opposite fashion.

Comment: @Adirio: So did I actually; originally I wrote it as a concatenation of `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase`, then realized that `ascii_letters` was already in the right order. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not as neat as the list pulled from the package `string` BUT it does solve your question by creating a single iterable by taking the union of two sets and should be quite efficient as well.

```
>>> [chr(i) for i in set(range(97,123)).union(range(65,91))]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Three notes: 1. Relying on `set`s to preserve order is a terrible idea (and as it happens, this is producing the wrong order, putting uppercase first, though somewhat surprisingly all the letters are otherwise in order). 2. You don't need to convert the argument to `union` to a `set`; it accepts arbitrary iterables (if you'd used `|` for unioning, you'd need both to be `set`s, but the named methods aren't particular). 3. There's no meaningful benefit to using `set`s here over just concatenating the `range`s; unpacking two `range`s to a `tuple` is faster for getting a single collection.

Comment: Hey there thanks for the enlightening! Learned a lot :D